# How to change colour of overlapped area of 2 divs using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a design, in which 2 divs overlap. However, the colour of overlapped area needs to be changed.

I tried to explore clipath\polygon. But I am not sure if that's the right direction, as I was not able to achieve using them.

Full code:
[JS Fiddle Example of this code](https://jsfiddle.net/xofp1dL5/21/)

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(234 54 67 / 50%);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure if this is possible by pure CSS. Might need to add JS and find all the intersections (but it will get hella messy)

Comment: Have you investigated mix-blend-mode?

Comment: Try looking into the mix-blend-mode property.

Comment: mix-blend-mode doesn't allow custom color right?

Comment: I did try mix-blend-mode. But I am not sure what property I need to use to achieve white. I tried all the types, but none of them gave me what I wanted.

Comment: Do you mean a pure white or are you wanting it to be the creamy color of that smaller square?

Comment: It's #F3F3F5 to be precise. But essentially, if there is a way to provide any colour we want. My div2 has a transparent background by the way. So not sure how mix-blend-mode would work then. I have updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xofp1dL5/24/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the mix-blend-mode property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode However, it may be difficult to get the overlapping area to be the color you want.

```css
.square1, .square2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.square1 {
  background-color: green;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.square2 {
  background-color: blue;
  /* there are a bunch of different options */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='square1'></div>
<div class='square2'></div>
```

Other than that, you are going to need a polygon clipping algorithm, which is quite complicated. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polygon-clipping-sutherland-hodgman-algorithm/

Comment: This may work for solid background colours, but for transparent background it isn't working well. I thought there could be some properties in css to do that, but looks like there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

simply change background of div2 in css like this and it changes to white:

```
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  left: 130px;
}
```

Comment: This will not work. As div2's background would be transparent and entire div will become white if it's background is changed: https://jsfiddle.net/7mctfydn/8/